# How to read complex json array in pyspark df?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have a json file that has below's structure that I need to read in as pyspark dataframe.

I tried reading in using multiLine option but it doesn't seem to return more data than the columns and datatypes. What am I possibly doing wrong and how can I read in belows'structure?

```
df = spark.read.format("json").option("inferSchema", "true") \
                         .option("multiLine", "true") \
                         .load("/mnt/blob/input/jsonfile.json")
```

Structure:

```
[
  [
    {
      "Key": "Val"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Val"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "Key": "Val"
    },
    {
      "Key": "Val"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: What does your expected output dataframe look like?

Comment: It should include the keys and values, right now I only retrieve the keys.. (sorry im not an experience pyspark developer)

Comment: Please provide tabular representation of your expected output. You have nested collection of records above. So, can not figure out if you expect scalers or arrays.